# GWT editor error message display time

Tags: gwt, gxt

I use GWT editor framework. I experience that the validation message disappears quickly. If it contains long text then the user can't read it. Is there any setting to change the display time of the validation message?

Comment: Which component are using? Some code, or at least the name of the widget you are using.

Comment: I have a com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.TextField which has a validator com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.Validator<T>
Here is a picture example: 
http://i.imgur.com/TBpI7Kl.png